# fPortfolio specify our constraints for efficientPortfolio

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, markowitz

I am working on the library fPortfolio in R and I have a question. How can we fix for a portfolio the sum of weights equal to 1 ? When I study the code, I see that we cannot choose which constraints on the efficientPortfolio problem we want as an inequality... Is it normal ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming and does not even provide a minimal working example. At the very least, please show how you have attempted to solve it and clearly state exactly what you are asking.